# Sonata User Bundle configuration error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I try to install Sonata User Bundle but I have a problem on configuration when I execute the command

```
app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle -d src
```

The git bash show this error :

```
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
  The service "sonata.user.orm.group_manager" has a dependency on a non-exist
  ent parameter "fos_user.model.group.class". Did you mean this: "fos_user.mo
  del.user.class"?
```

Answer (score 8):

In your configuration, you must have the following :

```
# app/config/sonata/user.yml or app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User     #Default configuration
    # ...
    group:
        group_class:   FOS\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager
```

You can replace FOSUserBundle entities by your own.

Answer (score 0):

You must install and configure the FOSUserBundle because SonataUserBundle is a bundle for integrate FOSUserBundle into a SonataProject.

You can read this installation doc for understand : [SonataUserBundle Install](https://www.sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html)

Did you notice the FosUserBundle into your AppKernel.php file like this :

```
public function registerbundles()
{
    return array(
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
        // ...
        // You have 2 options to initialize the SonataUserBundle in your AppKernel,
        // you can select which bundle SonataUserBundle extends
        // Most of the cases, you'll want to extend FOSUserBundle though ;)
        // extend the ``FOSUserBundle``
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
        // OR
        // the bundle will NOT extend ``FOSUserBundle``
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle(),
        // ...
    );
}
```